# How to download and decompress file from Ebay API

Tags: c#, gzip, ebay-api

I am attempting to get a file from Ebays API
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/feed/resources/task/methods/getResultFile#h2-samples

I am getting data back but it is not decompressing properly or encoding properly.  It should be an gziped xml file.  The documentation is not very clear on this actually.  I am using RestSharp for my http calls (106.15.0).
Exception:
Found invalid data while decoding

My Code:

```
const string url = "sell/feed/v1/task/task-16-SOMENUMBER/download_result_file";
        var restClient = new RestClient(_restApiUrl)
        {
            Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(authentication.AuthorizationToken, "Bearer")
            
        };

        var httpRequest = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
        httpRequest.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip");
        httpRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        byte[] myfile = restClient.DownloadData(httpRequest);
        var decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myfile);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(myfile))
        {
            string res;
            using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(zipStream))
                {
                    res = sr.ReadToEnd(); //ERROR HERE: Found invalid data while decoding
                }
            }
            var result = res;
        }
```

First 30 of returned string (Encoding.Default.GetString(myfile))
PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\0\b\b\b\0\f£†T\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0>\0\0\0ActiveInventoryReport

Hex
50-4B-03-04-14-00-08-08-08-00-0C-A3-86-54-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-3E-00-00-00-41-63-74-69-76-65-49-6E-76-65-6E-74-6F-72-79-52-65-70-6F-72-74-2D-41-70-72-2D-30-36-2D-32-30-32-32-2D-32-30-3A-32-34-3A-32-30-2D-30-37-30-30-2D-31-33-33-34-39-39-38-35-32-34-2E-78-6D-6C-BD-9D-5B-53-9B-47-B6-86-AF-77-7E-45-CA-F7-32-7D-3E-4C-79-3C-25-09-03-1E-C0-D6-48-38-60-DF-B1-8D-F6-98-0A-01-17-86-4C-3C-BF-7E-F7-E1-

Comment: Set position of MemoryStream to zero after filling. If that doesn'work, check file and make sure you are getting a file (not null) and verify it is gzip.

Comment: Read it as a string to see what it looks like. I would expect a `DownloadData` method to decompress it for you, when needed. If this doesn't help, you may check the first few bytes for compression. What is your response HTTP status? Are you sure the `token` is the first argument and `"Bearer"` is the second for the `Authenticator`? ...that seems backwards to me. I don't know anything about the client library you're using.

Comment: ...See [here](https://restsharp.dev/authenticators.html#oauth2) ...it seems the `token` is the second argument.

Comment: @rfmodulator I am definitely getting a file back.  When I decode it I see some expected words along with lots of jibberish.  I have tried multiple different encoding schemes also.

Comment: Please provide first 30 bytes or so in hexadecimal or Base64 in your question, so that we can determine some things about what the format is or isn't.

Comment: That's not GZip, it's a "normal" zip file (PKZip). Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0). The text you see: "ActiveInventoryReport-Apr-06-2022-20:24:20-0700-1334998524.xml" ...is the metadata, the original, uncompressed file's name.